# What is used by Toad for MySQL to change skins?

Tags: mysql, winforms, devexpress, toad, skin

I've just installed Toad for MySQL and on startup, I'm being asked to select a skin for the (winforms?) application. The impressive thing is that you can select from a huge list of skins and the app immediately updates.
Doing some Googling pointed me to the DevExpress control toolkit - is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Toad for MySQL is based on [DevExpress WinForms controls](http://devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/WhatsNew2012v1/winforms.xml). Thus the [DevExpress Skins technology](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2399) is available for this application out-of-the-box.
You can read more about Skins here: [Skins Overview](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2534).